# Moving rows to other sheets

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

Is there a way or formula that could move a certain row to a different sheet by just typing in the criteria and pressing enter?

Like if I have 3 sheets and one of the columns on each sheet was called status, and in this column I type COMP, could it move all the information to a sheet called COMP sheet?

Comment: You need a macro. Any experience with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert this code on your worksheets

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If (Range("A1").Value = "COMP") Then ' Replace "A1" for your cell that will contain COMP

    ActiveSheet.Range("1:1").Copy _       ' Replace  1:1 by your souce row
        Destination:=Worksheets("COMP").Range("2:2") 'replace 2:2 by your dest row


    End If
End Sub
```

When the user changes any value in the Worksheet, if the  value of "A1" is  "COMP", the row you chose (1 in the example) is copied into your destination row (row 2 in the example) in worksheet COMP.

Comment: Where in my sheet would i add this

Comment: also I could see this code working but for only one row I have like 5 different sheets that I want to use this code for so like if row 2:2 is full would this automatically go to the next row?

Comment: @daddycardona Sorry, this is a macro, they way Excel is programmed. Follow this screens http://www.xlpert.com/partA.htm and paste my code in each sheet where figure 1.2 shows.

Comment: @daddycardona just use Range("1:5") to copy the first 5 rows, and so on

Comment: @belisarius I can us rang(c2) vs (a1)? also what if i want like a dynamic add to (comp)because i dont know when i will be adding them would this code automatically go to the next row or replace what was already in (comp)row(2:2)?

Comment: @daddycardona You can use whatever range you want, Range("C2:H17") as origin will copy that rectangle. The same with the destination. It will overwrite whatever you previously have there, as you didn't specify to keep the data, and the code is much different.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a VBA Macro that does all of the moving for you, but that would require the user to manually run it, not just typing COMP in a cell.  You can also have it update automatically without the user pressing COMP and enter by using a formula that references the other worksheets (but then it will always be there).

```
=Sheet1!A1
```

The above code will reference the top left cell in the Worksheet 'Sheet1'.